# Implementing REST hypermedia using WCF

Tags: wcf, rest, hypermedia

I have a WCF-based REST service and I'm planning to add hypermedia support to it. Currently I'm relying on WCF to build the service response by serializing my data contracts. With hypermedia in the picture now, I need a way to instruct WCF to insert hypermedia links in the XML response that it builds. My question is, how do I do that?

One way could be that I modify my data contracts to include the said links as data members. Then WCF can automatically serialize them. But is that the best practice? Or is it better to intercept WCF's serialization process and add these links at that time? Or is there any other more suitable alternative?

Answer (score 2):

You need to construct the hypermedia yourself. If you choose Atom there are some helpers. Basically you create a SyndicationFeed and add SyndicationItem items to it and use an Atom10FeedFormatter to turn the whole feed into an Atom document.